# g++: error trying to exec 'jc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, oracle11g, g++-4.7

I was trying to compile my cpp code using g++ and every time i  am getting this error:

```
g++: error trying to exec 'jc1': execvp: No such file or directory.
```

I am executing this command:

```
g++  -L/root/Shared/instantclient_11_2_lib/* -L $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/lib/* -L $ORACLE_HOME/lib/* cpp_db_conn.cpp
```

My cpp programme contains code for connection with oracle db.
My cpp code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "/root/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include/occi.h"

using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std;

int main(){

    oracle::occi::Environment* environment;
    oracle::occi::Connection* con;
    oracle::occi::Statement* stmt;
    oracle::occi::ResultSet* res;

    try {

        environment = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
        con = environment->createConnection("tkmah7u", "root", "XE");

        stmt = con->createStatement("select * from customers");
        res = stmt->executeQuery();

        while (res->next())
            std::cout<<res->getInt(1)<<"  "<<res->getString(2)<<std::endl;

        stmt->closeResultSet(res);
        con->terminateStatement(stmt);
        environment->terminateConnection(con);
    }catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e){
        std::cout<<e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are linking with the compiler *root/Shared/instantclient_11_2_lib/*

Then your `#include` should be :

```
#include <occi.h>
```

I tried your code and I had only reapeting error on your file including (after solving, just get more others), so the problem should be somewhere around *occi.h*.